# Larvel 5.4 +SMTP +Gmail + Aws EC2 ubuntu 16 not working Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, smtp, gmail, laravel-5.4

I have tried each Possible solution mentioned accross site but still i am unable to send smtp mail using Gmail on AWS EC2 ubuntu 16 but the same code is working on rackserver ubuntu 16.

Here the solutions i tried

following code in config/mail.php

```
driver : "smtp",
host : "smtp.gmail.com",
port : 587,
address: "toadysapps@gmail.com",
encryption : "tls"  or "ssl" //tried alternate
username : "toadysapps@gmail.com"
password : mypassword or gmail appkey // tried both alternate
```

i have enabled less secure password in gmail.
 Tried the following solution

```
sudo nano /etc/gai.conf
```

Uncomment the following line (remove the #):

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-not-sending-emails-in-aws-ec2-ubuntu-1604?page=1

Below are my security groups in aws ec2
[image: OutBound Rule]
[image: Inbound Rule]

Please help me someone what i am missing or what should i do.

Comment: whats the error ? set the logging level on php to see what error do you get or I think you can look at mail logs in ubuntu.

Comment: @JamesDean I am getting error Expected response code 250 but got code “”, with message “” swift transport error